# Practice of avoiding saying "A Freilichin Chanukah"

Tags: blessing, chanuka, hukot-hagoyim

A Skvere chosid told me today that his minhag and the minhag of other chassidim is not to wish anyone "A Freilichin Chanukah" because they understand it as a copy of the "Merry Christmas" greeting and therefore in some way included in chukas ha'goy. Does anyone know how prevalent or widespread this "minhag" is and when it started?  I'm not asking about the Halachic validity of the "minhag" but just about its source and whether it is actually followed by any significant amount of people.

Comment: `whether it is actually followed by any significant amount of people.` May be Jews; not Judaism.

Comment: @mevaqesh. Isn't chukas ha'goy part of "Judiasm"?

Comment: It is, but this question ignores the halakhic component of whether it is or isnt. Rather it asks about a particular practice, regardless of whether it is a halakhic one or a mere social convention (based perhaps on a mistake), and asks about its popularity.

Comment: @mevaqesh. Isn't a practice followed by a significant amount of Jews based on a Torah law (correctly or incorrectly) included in questions about Judiasm that this site proposes to help people find answers to?

Comment: It may also depend on the machlokes wether Chanukah is a yom tov "lesimcha" or just hallel and hodah.

Comment: curious if this in any way relates to the bleak view we take toward the Hasmonean dynasty for the decades FOLLOWING Chanukah... since they illegitimately claimed the ascendancy to the throne and we don't want to legitimize the holiday they instituted for their own victory...